# Numeric YYYMM SAS field... Want to convert to an actual date field YYYYMM

Tags: sas

I currently have a dataset that has a field that contains YYYYMM in a numeric format... How can I convert this to an actual date field in the same layout?

Here is the expression I'm trying to use:

```
Input(put(t1.LOAN_MONTH_YR_NR,f8.0),yymmdd.)
```

t1.Loan_Month_YR_NR is the field that has 201707 as a number.

Comment: As posted this question does not meet SO guidelines. You need to post what you've tried so far, and ideally some sample data that allows us to understand your problem. To meet SO guidelines please add these components and review the How to Ask a Good question post.

Comment: To do the conversion you'll need to first convert to character using PUT and then use INPUT to read it as a date.

Comment: My apologies...   Here is the expression I'm trying to use:

Input(put(t1.LOAN_MONTH_YR_NR,f8.0),yymmdd.)

t1.Loan_Month_YR_NR is the field that has 201707 as a number

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers only have 6 digits, not 8, so you are using the wrong FORMAT to convert to character and the wrong INFORMAT to convert to date.  You should also attach a format if you want them to look the same when printed (even though the actual value will be different).

```
select input(put(t1.LOAN_MONTH_YR_NR,z6.),yymmn6.) format=yymmn6. as LOAN_MONTH_YR_DT
from t1
```